# Javascript + jQuery + function that implements getters and setters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting to learn JavaScript and jQuery, and there is a small JavaScript concept that I do not understand at all. It is about functions, setters and getters. Here is the code example.

As you can see, when I click on a markup, a dialog form opens, I get data through the dialog-form, save it into two objects (`myHeader` and `myContent`), and finally use it.

- The first `console.log` executed is `(1)` and it prints `'hi'`.
- The second `console.log` is `(2)`, and it prints the content saved into the object `myHeader`.
- But the `console.log` number `(3)`, sometimes doesn't print anything, or it prints `undefined`.

What am I misunderstanding about JavaScript functions?

```
$(function() {

$(".myMarkup").click(function() {   
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog("open", function() {
        console.log(myHeader.getContent());  //(3)
    });
});


Header = function() {
    var val='hi';
    this.getContent = function() { return val; }
    this.setContent = function(x) { val = x; }
};

Content = function() {
    var val='hi';
    this.getContent = function() { return val; }
    this.setContent = function(x) { val = x; }
};

var myContent = new Content();
var myHeader = new Header();
    console.log(myHeader.getContent());  //(1)


$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Modify": function() {
    a = document.getElementById('name').value.toString();
    b = document.getElementById('surname').value.toString();    
    myHeader.setContent(a);
    myContent.setContent(b);
    console.log(myHeader.getContent(a)); //(2)
    },
  }
)};
```

Comment: From the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open -- The `open` method does not accept any arguments.  I don't see how `(3)` would ever be reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not with function, setter or getter. Problem is on how use are using dialogue API.
It look like you want a callback function on open event so for that you can either add callback during initialization.

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
//your options +
open:function() {
        console.log(myHeader.getContent());  
    }

});
```

or set later before calling open method

```
$(".myMarkup").click(function() {   

    $( "#dialog-form" ).bind( "dialogopen", function() {
        console.log(myHeader.getContent());  //(3)
    }).dialog("open");
});
```

open method does not accept any argument so there will be only parameter.

I will suggest you to have look on its api documentation before using any api.
[api.jqueryui.com/dialog/](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Other syntax error i found is you are not properly closing the brackets.

`)}`; will be `});` with an extra `});` for your `$(function() {`

Comment: thanks for your time. My issue is that at the console.log number (3), i need the data recorded in myHeader and myContent from the dialog-form. The issue is that the console logs a 'hi', in stead of the data written at the dialog-form. Thats the reason i wanted to create a callback, so after the dialog-form is finished, and new data incorporated into myHeader and myContent, i can use it.There is some kind of sync issue. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: let me know if this solves your problem http://jsfiddle.net/8ZBsV/2/. As i don't find any sync issue. Only the thing is how you are using callback function.

Comment: thanks for your information. The "bind" function is really the answer. A way of creating a "callback", where after you finish the dialog-form, you continue with the rest of the code, and not in parallel. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seams to me like a timing-problem:

Take your myHeader & myContent-Declaration out of the jQuery-Ready-Callback, or put it on the very beginning.